# Эмулятор интернет и локальной сети

Tags: подсети, сеть, настройка

нужна программа в которой можно наглядно поэкспериментировать с настройками локальной сети и не только, чтоб там и маршрутизаторы были и сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cisco Packet Tracer
2. GNS3

Второе посложнее, но то что вам нужно. В первом можно конфигурировать тока сетевое оборудование, во втором все.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ для Zerglyn: Остапа действительно понесло, ибо GNS (Graphical Network Simulator) плотно интегрирован с VirtualBox, о чём они заявляют прямо на главной странице! И смысл проекта GNS, косвенно, в том, чтобы сделать графическую среду для эмуляции сети между виртуальными гостевыми системами, но это не самое главное! Главная цель проекта GNC - моделирование сложных структур компьютерных сетей, с применением эмуляции различных роутеров!

Comment: Щаз попробую:)

Comment: И правда - аппетитная штучка... Изучаю...)

Answer (score 1):

Поднимаешь две виртуальные машины, даешь им IP из одной подсети - вот уже есть виртуальная локалка. Подними еще одну, сделай ее шлюзом и пусти в подсеть хоста - вот уже и виртуальная локалка с выходом в "Интернет". Пусти внешний интерфейс "шлюза" в Интернет и вот оно счастье.

Ну а дальше - ограничивает только полет фантазии... Можно таким образом собрать микродомен со своим DC, можно поднять две разных подсети, ткнуть между ними "маршрутизатор", DNS, поднять пару виртуальных сайтов, почту, пустить виртуальную машину и......

"И тут Остапа понесло..."(с)